# Returns incorrect output

Tags: c#

Description of challenge:

Have the function KaprekarsConstant(num) take the num parameter being passed which will be a 4-digit number with at least two distinct digits.

Your program should perform the following routine on the number:

- Arrange the digits in descending order and in ascending order (adding
  zeroes to fit it to a 4-digit number), and subtract the smaller
  number from the bigger number. Then repeat the previous step.
- Performing this routine will always cause you to reach a fixed number: 6174.
- Then performing the routine on 6174 will always give you 6174 (7641 - 1467 = 6174). 
  Your program should return the number of times this routine must be performed until 6174 is reached.

For example: if num is 3524 your program should return 3 because of the following steps:

1. 5432 - 2345 = 3087
2. 8730 - 0378 = 8352
3. 8532 - 2358 = 6174

Web-site where I took this challenge Coderbyte

Problem :

All works correctly until returning the result in `Foo()` I don't know why but it calls this function some times until `Count==2`

Please help.Sorry please if I made mistakes and my code is really bad because I am schooler(9 Grade) and I have been programming for half a year

```cs
using System;

class MainClass
{ 
    public static int Foo(int num,int Counter)
    {
        int Count = Counter;
        int[] arr = new int[4];
        arr[0] = num / 1000;
        arr[1] = num % 10;
        arr[2] = (num / 100) % 10;
        arr[3] = (num % 100) / 10;
        Array.Sort(arr);
        int[] AscArr = new int[4];
        arr.CopyTo(AscArr, 0);
        Array.Reverse(arr);
        int[] DescArr = arr;
        int sub = 0;
        string AscStr = string.Empty;
        string DescStr = string.Empty;
        for (int i = 0; i < AscArr.Length; i++)
        {
            AscStr += AscArr[i];
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < DescArr.Length; i++)
        {
            DescStr += DescArr[i];
        }
        int b = int.Parse(AscStr);
        int a = int.Parse(DescStr);
        sub = a - b;

        if (sub!=6174)
        {
            Count++;
            Foo(sub,Count);
        }
        if (sub==6174)
        {
            Count++;


        }

        return Count;

    }
    public static int KaprekarsConstant(int num)
    {
        int[] arr=new int[4];
        arr[0] = num / 1000;
        arr[1] = num % 10;
        arr[2] = (num / 100) % 10;
        arr[3] = (num % 100) / 10;
        Array.Sort(arr);
        int[] AscArr=new int[4];
        arr.CopyTo(AscArr,0);
        Array.Reverse(arr);
        int[] DescArr = arr;
        int sub = 0 ;
        string AscStr=string.Empty;
        string DescStr = string.Empty;
        for (int i = 0; i < AscArr.Length; i++)
        {
            AscStr += AscArr[i];
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < DescArr.Length; i++)
        {
            DescStr += DescArr[i];
        }
        int b = int.Parse(AscStr);
        int a = int.Parse(DescStr);
        sub = a - b;
        int Counter =1;
        int Count=0;
        if (Count!=6174)
        {
            Count = Foo(sub, Counter);
        }



        return Count;

    }

    static void Main()
    {
        // keep this function call here
        Console.WriteLine(KaprekarsConstant(int.Parse(Console.ReadLine())));
    }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Its not a bad question, just had some formatting issues

Comment: [Recursion](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/recursion/)

Comment: Also, instead of recursion you can make a loop: `while (num != 6174) ...`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is too much complex, plus, your way of dividing number to `array` is giving wrong results.

```
// this is wrong you can print array, the numbers goes into wrong indexes 
arr[0] = num / 1000;
arr[1] = num % 10;
arr[2] = (num / 100) % 10;
arr[3] = (num % 100) / 10;
```

Use this:

```
using System;
class MainClass
{ 
    public static int count = 0;
    public static void KaprekarsConstant(int num)
    {
        if (num == 6174)  // base case
            return;
        count++;

        string[] Aarr=new string[4];
        string[] Darr = new string[4];
        string asc = "", dsc = "";

        Aarr[3] = (num % 10).ToString();
        Darr[3] = (num % 10).ToString();
        num /= 10;
        Aarr[2] =(num % 10).ToString();
        Darr[2] = (num % 10).ToString();
        num /= 10;
        Aarr[1] = (num % 10).ToString();
        Darr[1] = (num % 10).ToString();
        num /= 10;
        Aarr[0] =(num % 10).ToString();
        Darr[0] = (num % 10).ToString();

        Array.Sort(Aarr);  // ascneding sorted
        Array.Sort<string>(Darr, new Comparison<string>( (i1, i2) => i2.CompareTo(i1)));   // descending sorted

        for(int i = 0; i< 4;i++)
        {
            asc += Aarr[i];
            dsc += Darr[i];
        }
        KaprekarsConstant(Convert.ToInt32(dsc) -Convert.ToInt32(asc) );
}

    static void Main()
    {
        KaprekarsConstant(int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()));
        Console.WriteLine("\nIt took "+count + "times to reach 6174");
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not one of the best approach, but it runs correctly haha :-)

Comment: Read the problem

Comment: It states “number should have atleast 2 different digits it”